# why this statment work well in java but badly in android?

Tags: java, android, httpclient

```
SchemeRegistry supportedSchemes = new SchemeRegistry();
supportedSchemes.register(new Scheme("http", 80, PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory()));
```

This statement work well in java but badly in android? I had add httpclient_4.1.3.jar in my referenced dependencies and android dependencies.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. What is the exception or problem?

Comment: An untrained answer would be because it's not a regular JVM, but Dalvik and it's not running on your standard OS, but on Android.

Comment: @Averroes eclipse say The constructor Scheme(String, int, PlainSocketFactory) is undefined

Comment: @Buffalo So how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such constructor for Scheme, as you can see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/conn/scheme/Scheme.html) There is [a similar one](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/conn/scheme/Scheme.html#Scheme%28java.lang.String,%20org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory,%20int%29) you can use though. Here is an example from the linked Javadoc page:

```
Scheme https = new Scheme("https", new MySecureSocketFactory(), 443);
SchemeRegistry.DEFAULT.register(https);
```

Or to adapt your code to this:

```
Scheme http = new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80);
SchemeRegistry.DEFAULT.register(http);
```

Comment: Are you sure it is related with the JVM difference? I add your code in my code and it also report error.

Comment: @user1614589: Is it the same error? This code should work. Are you sure all your dependencies are in order?

Comment: I change your code to `Scheme https = new Scheme("https", SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443);` and it didn't report error. And how to assure all my dependencies in order? I put all of the jars in libs forder and add them in android dependencies and referenced dependencies ...Actually, I am a fresher.

Comment: @user1614589: That should be it then, you notice if you don't have all the dependencies. If Eclipse is happy, the code should work. Added an adaption of your code to my answer.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, the error information is "DEFAULT cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: @user1614589: Ok, strange example on the javadoc page then. Replace the second row with `SchemeRegistry supportedSchemes = new SchemeRegistry();` and register to that then as you did first.

Comment: Another question, in [link](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/scheme/Scheme.html) I see your method is "Deprecated", I think the root problem didn't get solved, but I thank you all the same, and can you give me a better idea?

Comment: @user1614589: That method isn't used in this example, no methods on `Scheme` are called here. I'm sorry, I'm not sure of how much more help I can be then.